# OUYA Developer Kit throws various errors on start

Tags: android, ouya

I followed [these instructions](https://devs.ouya.tv/developers/docs/setup) for Mac OS X using an existing IDE (shell + text editor) instead of the Eclipse ADT thingy. I activated “Use Host GPU”, and installed Intel HAXM.
Installing the ouya-framework.apk and ouya-launcher.apk appears to go well. But when I start up my AVD there’s a dialog box saying “Unfortunately, the OUYA Launcher has stopped.”, I still get the choice of starting up the OUYA Launcher. When I do so there’s another dialog box saying “Can’t play this video”. I skip the controller settings, and then there’s a JOIN A WIRELESS NETWORK screen which I can’t get past.

This is the ODK 1.0.2, and I tried it using both Mac OS X 10.8.3 and 10.7.5.

Answer (score 2):

The wireless network problem [has been discussed on the OUYA forums](http://forums.ouya.tv/discussion/comment/9638/#Comment_9638). It seems impossible to proceed beyond that point on an Android emulator. You’ll need to test on a real device.

This isn’t only an OS X problem: I’ve encountered similar problems (“OUYA Launcher has stopped” and “Can’t play this video”) on Windows too.

Comment: Hmph. Are you saying that the ODK is not intended to be used on the emulator?